# Is there any archival time for app data, if we make GKE node count to 0

Tags: database, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanted Cost optimization, when there is no use off an Application.

So for that I make my GKE node count to 0. Just for testing I made node count to 1, to check the my app data is there or not.

After making node count 1, the data is there, but my question is I just turned the count 1 from 0 for testing within few minutes.

The real Question is there any Archival time there for app data ?

lets say I make node count 0 and come back after 3 months or 6 months and make count 1, does my data still available there ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of storage. By default, persistent disk are used and are binded to the VM. If you remove the VM the disk is removed. And you loose your data

If you use a NFS storage, like Filestore service, the storage is not binded to the VM and you can safely scale to 0 without losing data.

However, considering your question, I'm pretty sure you use the first option. Therefore a backup (disk snapshot) is required before scaling to 0, and then a restore with your scale again.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume your comments are helpful

Comment: So If I use Persistent Volume, after deleting the node also, my data will be there right ?

Comment: No! If you delete, the VM, the persistent disk is released and your data lost!

Comment: Hey Guillaume, I'm talking about persistent volume not disk

Comment: Hmmm, you have to deep dive a little bit so. The persistent volume is the Kubernetes representation of a disk. It can be implemented in different way by the Cloud Provider. On google cloud, it's a persistent disk by default. By it can also be a NFS share, like Filestore. More details here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#persistentvolumes